# Do I use this equation for a Friis law question

Tags: noise

I am just puzzled as the question gives two gains.

The question is below

*input receiver has a noise figure of 4db and a power gain of 5db. It is followed by a mixer stage of with a noise figure of 3.5db and a gain of 3db. what is the composite noise figure for the two stages*

[image: Friss equation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gain of the first stage is included in NF1.

Noise figure is the noise factor converted to dB.

Noise factor for an amplifier is (SNRin)/(SNRout).  SNRout already includes the gain (plus additional noise contribution) of the first stage.

This is why (other posts here have described this) it's important that the first amplifier or device in a chain have the lowest noise figure.

Comment: So use this equation? As the  mixer stage gain is not needed?

Comment: Just like NF1, the mixer gain is already included in NF2.

Comment: So this equation is used to find the composite noise figure?

Comment: Yes.  You can use the Friis equation to compute the overall noise figure for any number of stages in a chain.